How to exactly GeometricSolveValues this problem?
I am solving with Mathematica 14.1 on Windows the following geometric problem

In a right-angled triangle, the ratio of the radius of the circum-circle to
the radius of the in-circle equals 5/2.
Find he values of the acute angles of this triangle

by
GeometricSolveValues[ GeometricScene[{a, b, c}, {Triangle[{a, b, c}],
EuclideanDistance[a, c] <= EuclideanDistance[b, c], 
ArcLength[CircleThrough[{a, b, c}]]/ArcLength[Insphere[{a, b, c}]] == 5/2, 
PlanarAngle[{a, c, b}] == Pi/2}], PlanarAngle[{c, a, b}]]


{0.927295}

I'd like to obtain ArcTan[4/3] or -ArcSin[7*Sqrt[2]/10] + 3*Pi/4
as the answer because I was learned that geometry is exact.
Following that recent thread,
I try
 GeometricScene[{{a -> {0, 1}, b -> {x, 0}, c -> {0, 0}}, {x}}, {x > 1,
Triangle[{a, b, c}],   ArcLength[CircleThrough[{a, b, c}]]/
ArcLength[Insphere[{a, b, c}]] == 5/2, PlanarAngle[{a, c, b}] == Pi/2}]["AlgebraicFormulation"]//InputForm


Exists[{C[1], C[2], C[3], C[4], C[5], C[6]}, x == Indexed[b, {1}] && Indexed[a, {1}] == 0 && Indexed[a, {2}] == 1 &&  Indexed[b, {2}] == 0 && Indexed[c, {1}] == 0 && * (-(Indexed[b, {2}]*Indexed[c, {1}]) + Indexed[a, {2}]*(-Indexed[b, {1}] + Indexed[c, {1}]) +  Indexed[a, {1}]*(Indexed[b, {2}] - Indexed[c, {2}]) + Indexed[b, {1}]*Indexed[c, {2}])^4 && x > 1 && ... C[4] > 0 && 0 < C[1] < 1 && 0 < C[2] < 1 && 0 < C[3] < 1]

(its LeafCount is 1564)
and
Resolve[%,Reals]

is running without any response during more than an hour.
The solution by hand is not difficult:
Reduce[Sqrt[1 + x^2]*(1 + x + Sqrt[1 + x^2])/x/2 == 5/2 && x >= 1, x, Reals]

However, I am inerested in the exact solution in the frame of synthetic geometry.

@The down-voters: What is incorrect in my question? It is unfair to down vote without any explaining comment.

I’m voting to close this question because this user is recalcitrant in accepting rational answers and there is no value to the site.


Follow the secondary approach by author but use Reduce[..., θ, {x}] to elimate {x}.

Clear["Global`*"];
a = {0, 1};
b = {x, 0};
c = {0, 0};
sol = Reduce[{ArcLength@CircleThrough[{a, b, c}]/
     ArcLength@Insphere[{a, b, c}] == 5/2, 
   x > 1, θ == PlanarAngle[{c, a, b}]}, θ, {x}]


θ == ArcTan[4/3]


Thank you for your work. In fact, this is nothing but  Reduce[Sqrt[1 + x^2]*(1 + x + Sqrt[1 + x^2])/x/2 == 5/2 && x >= 1, x, Reals]. as in my question. I find θ == PlanarAngle[{c, a, b}]}, θ, {x} made by hand. Also don't see GeometricScene and GeometricSolveValues. Thank you anyway.

@user64494  I am not a GeometricScrene user and  I don't think it can do more thing than Reduce and Solve.  GeometricSolveValues[  GeometricScene[{a, b, c}, {Triangle[{a, b, c}],     EuclideanDistance[a, c] <= EuclideanDistance[b, c],     ArcLength[CircleThrough[{a, b, c}]]/      ArcLength[Insphere[{a, b, c}]] == 5/2,     PlanarAngle[{a, c, b}] == Pi/2}],   EuclideanDistance[b, c]/EuclideanDistance[a, c]] we only get 4/3.

Or GeometricSolveValues[  GeometricScene[{a, b, c}, {Triangle[{a, b, c}],     EuclideanDistance[a, c] <= EuclideanDistance[b, c],     ArcLength[CircleThrough[{a, b, c}]]/      ArcLength[Insphere[{a, b, c}]] == 5/2,     PlanarAngle[{a, c, b}] == Pi/2}], (b - a) . (c - a)/(  Norm[b - a] Norm[c - a])]  we get {3/5}

Unfortunately, GeometricSolveValues[  GeometricScene[{{a -> {0, 1}, b -> {x, 0}, c -> {0, 0}}, {x}}, {x >      1, Triangle[{a, b, c}],     ArcLength[CircleThrough[{a, b, c}]]/      ArcLength[Insphere[{a, b, c}]] == 5/2,     PlanarAngle[{a, c, b}] == Pi/2}], PlanarAngle[{c, a, b}]] returns {0.927649} on my comp in several minutes.

Perhaps a work around:
gs = GeometricScene[{{a, b, c, ci}, {x, y}}, {Triangle[{a, b, c}], 
    PlanarAngle[{c, a, b}] == Pi/2, EuclideanDistance[b, c] == 5, 
    Circumsphere[{a, b, c}], 
    ci == TriangleConstruct[{a, b, c}, "Incenter"], 
    Circle[ci, 1] == Insphere[{a, b, c}], 
    x == EuclideanDistance[a, c], y == EuclideanDistance[a, b]}];
Row[RandomInstance[gs, 2]]
tan = GeometricSolveValues[gs, x/y][[1]]
{u, v} /. 
 Solve[Tan[u] == tan && Cot[v] == tan && 0 < u < Pi/2 && 
    0 < v < Pi/2, {u, v}][[1]]
N[%] 180/Pi


Note:

the condition regarding the ratio of radii is handled differently avoiding the overhead of ArcLength. Failure to understand this is not in my control.
The point of this answer is concordant with @cvgmt


This is not it. You don't use the condition ArcLength[CircleThrough[{a, b, c}]]/ArcLength[Insphere[{a, b, c}]] == 5/2. Moreover, you even don't verify it for your triangle in your answer..

https://i.sstatic.net/UDTpKgCE.png … OK, let me explain it. @user64494 ubpdqn has actually used that condition, it's EuclideanDistance[b, c] == 5 and Circle[ci, 1] == Insphere[{a, b, c}]. Of course, manual analysis has involved in, the conclusion "the hypotenuse of a right triangle is the diameter of circumcircle" has been used, and the condition has been modified to "the radius of the circum-circle is 5/2 and the radius of the in-circle is 1", but as a work-around, I think it's acceptable.
